# REGEX to match yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: regex, date, format

Hello guys i'm trying to find a regular expression to match only the date in this string:

```
"$date" : "2019-07-10T17:34:01.222Z"
```

so i can get something like

```
2019-07-10T17:34:01.222Z
```

how could i achieve this

Comment: PHP? , why not using  split for achieving that output?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this expression might just work OK:

```
\"\$date\"\s*:\s*"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[A-Z]\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+[A-Z])"
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RfhCTI/1/)

```js
const regex = /\"\$date\"\s*:\s*"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[A-Z]\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+[A-Z])"/gm;
const str = `"\$date" : "2019-07-10T17:34:01.222Z"`;
const subst = `$1`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```